# WordPress showing "Home Tagline" instead of tagline

Tags: wordpress

My site is [here](http://wp.mk-code.com/), and the problem is obvious. Why is the tagline not updating?

Sorry for the short post, didn't see how to make it any longer.

Comment: show us the relevant code from whatever PHP file is used to output that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go to Customize and there was a Home Tagline option there. (I'm totally new to WordPress.)